# itextsharp : Index was outside the bounds of the array when inserting binary image to PDF

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, itext

I have a base64 string which is static and i inserted it manually into the code, and it works fine: see below

```
    string base64 = @"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApIA.........";
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    iTextSharp.text.Image TechSig = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
```

i now have signauture canvas that saves a different base64 string to SQL database each time it is saved, I want to pull the new base64 string that has been saved to DB and load it into a string variable.

Once loaded into the string variable i would like to replace the long base64 string (line above conversion to byte) with the new declared varible that has info from DB e.g

```
    Public string ClientSigImg;
    string base64 = ClientSigImg.Substring(ClientSigImg.IndexOf(",") + 1);
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    iTextSharp.text.Image CustSig = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
```

when i replace it i get an error Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: On which line do you get `Index was outside the bounds of the array` error`?

Comment: iTextSharp.text.Image CustSig = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);

Comment: Then you have no other choice: you either debug the library (iTextSharp) yourself, or file a bug.

Comment: To further what @data said, grab the official iTextSharp source, add it to your project and debug. Its actually really easy. Also, try writing `imageBytes` out to disk as an image and make sure the image isn't corrupt.